# Ping failure monitor

Tags: networking

the network frequently fails and I would like to monitor the output. I tried to makeshift a command like:

```
ping www.google.fr | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done 1>/dev/null && 2> ~/ping_err.log
```

but the STDERR is still redirected to STDOUT instead ping_err.log

note: 
I want only STDERR in the file (not 2>&1)

Thanks!

Comment: I can't test it right now, but shouldn't it work if you omit the `&&`?

Comment: actually, the && was added but the stderr is still on the screen

Answer (score 2):

Rather than answer your `stderr` redirection question, I'll suggest a better (IMHO) way:

In `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git` - Watch for (WiFi) network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it.

There's a way to monitor your connection:

```
  ip monitor address | \
    egrep --line-buffered \
    '^Deleted [[:digit:]]+: [[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]+inet[[:space:]].* scope global ' | \
    while read line ; do
       ...
```

My `net-o-matic` script also contains a way to ask once:

```
function netstate () {
    # Return network state as "UP" or "DOWN"
    #Adjust how you decide net is UP/DOWN
    ip link show | egrep -q 'UP,LOWER_UP.* state UP'
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
        echo "UP"
    else
        echo "DOWN"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your code, this seems to work:

```sh
$ ping www.google.fr 2>&1 > /dev/null | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong" ; done 2>&1 > ping_err.log
[no output]
$ cat ping_err.log

vie jul  5 15:56:09 -03 2019: ping: sendmsg: La red es inaccesible
vie jul  5 15:56:10 -03 2019: ping: sendmsg: La red es inaccesible
vie jul  5 15:56:11 -...
```

Comment: great work, nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

I expanded @schrodigerscatcuriosity's answer a bit with:

```
ping -i 10 -O -q 192.168.88.2 2>&1 | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong" ; done 2>&1 | tee ping_err.log
```

- `-i 10` wait 10 seconds before sending each packet
- `-O` for logging outstanding ICMP ECHO reply before sending next packet
- `-q` for quiet output (except for timeouts)
- `| tee` to simultaneously print the output to console and file